# Need an XSL to update the datetime attribute value of an xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Here is my source XML:

```
<Chat>
  <Chat StartTime="2017-05-28T02:05:52"> 
    <message userId="02A0592964A8F75F" timeShift="4">
      <msgText> Hi </msgText> 
    </message>
    <message userId="123458566666666B"  timeShift="30"> 
      <msgText> Hello.. How can I Help You. ? </msgText> 
    </message>
</Chat>
```

I need an XSL to trnsform the source as:

```
 <Chats>
     <message time="2017-05-28T02:05:56" userId="02A0592964A8F75F">Hi</message>
     <message time="2017-05-28T02:06:32" userId="02A0592964A8F75F">Hello.. How can I Help You. ?</message> 
 </Chats>
```

In the output XML file, message time should be updated with the StartTime based on TimeShift(seconds).

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use XSLT 2.0, then your transform will look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" extension-element-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Chats>
      <xsl:variable name="timeShift" select="Chat/@StartTime"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="Chat/message">
        <message>
          <xsl:attribute name="time">
            <xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime($timeShift) + xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT', @timeShift,'S'))"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="userId">
            <xsl:value-of select="@userId"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="msgText"/>
        </message>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Chats>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It makes the following result:

```
<Chats>
   <message time="2017-05-28T02:05:56" userId="02A0592964A8F75F"> Hi </message>
   <message time="2017-05-28T02:06:22" userId="123458566666666B"> Hello.. How can I Help You. ? </message>
</Chats>
```

It's a bit different from yours:

```
<Chats>
     <message time="2017-05-28T02:05:56" userId="02A0592964A8F75F">Hi</message>
     <message time="2017-05-28T02:06:32" userId="02A0592964A8F75F">Hello.. How can I Help You. ?</message> 
 </Chats>
```

So I have a question. Do you need to shift from StartTime or the previous message?

Comment: Hi.... Thank you very much for such a quick response But, I it is throwing the following error when I say XSTobject.Transform(): 

{"Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'."}

Comment: I need to shift from StartTime........

each message time should be calculated based on Timeshift,
i.e Messagetime = StartTime + Timeshift (Seconds)

Comment: Ok then the date calculates correctly. As for the error, it look like it does not support version="2.0". If you want to use version 2.0 with .NET then you need to use third party tools, either the .NET version of Saxon 9 or AltovaXML tools. Maybe rewrite the transform to use version 1.0